# Why does Selenium move element to the top before clicking in Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, selenium

When I try to do a simple click on a link element in firefox browser, it doesn't work. In IE it does. I noticed that selenium makes ff scroll the web page so that the element its gonna click is at the very top left. Problem is that on certain sites like yahoo a message bar will show up when you scroll the page and it will cover that element making it not clickable. IE doesn't do any scrolling and that is why the same code works. How can we prevent element from having to be at the top of page?

```
// WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pa-u_17986569-bd']/a/span[2]")).click();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some javascript event bound on the element that you are clicking on? I am guessing the event is bubbling up. If you do have some listener attached on that link make sure you `return false` at the end of the callback.

Comment: Hi Baz1nga that element is just the Sports link on yahoo.com left side column. The only code I used to automate is the code in the original post. Why does it have to scroll?